# What is the idea or algorithm behind finding n-gram in NLTK?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, n-gram

I am using Python NLTK package to generate 2-gram and 3-gram from my corpus. But I can't find how NLTK can generate them from a corpus.

I found this one here: [An Introduction to N-grams: What Are They and Why Do We Need Them?](https://blog.xrds.acm.org/2017/10/introduction-n-grams-need/), but I wonder if there are any other algorithms to find n-grams. And does NLTK use the algorithm in this article to find n-grams?

And as always, thank you so much.

Comment: You can find the source code for NLTK's `ngrams`, `bigrams` and `trigrams` modules here: https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/util.html

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over pairs / triplets / n-length sequences of words in a sentence as tuples using zip.

```
for s in sentences:
    for w1, w2 in zip(s, s[1:]):
        bigram = w1, w2
```